# What is the best way to check whether a browser extension has finished installing in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

A browser extension can be installed for a `ChromeDriver` object by using the following code:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addExtensions(new File(pathToExtension));
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

This works perfectly, however I'd like to check whether installation of this extension is completed. Is there a way to do this in Selenium? I know how to let Selenium wait for a given amount of time, but I wondered if there is a cleaner solution.

Comment: The driver extracts the extension in the profile before launching the browser. So the extension is already installed when the browser is launched.

Comment: Thanks, no need to check then :)